# jquery datepicker in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, datepicker

whats wrong with the below code, its throwing me an error of 
Compiler Error Message: CS1002: ; expected

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $('<%=StartDate.UniqueID%>').datepicker({ showOn: 'button',
          buttonImage: '../images/Calendar.png',
          buttonImageOnly: true, onSelect:
                function() { },
          onClose: function() { $(this).focus(); }
      }); 
    });

<label for="sd">StartDate:</label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="StartDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

**error**

```
The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the reason i was getting the error:

"Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method"

because i was having conflict .js reference and there were two different set of .js on the page

hope this helps other.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this saved me a bunch of time.  I am using Telerik MVC menu and had a script block on the page that was referencing the jquery-1.4.2.min also so I had two references.

Comment: worked for me; i was using datepicker, slideshow, jspane custom scroller on same page. i removed the jquery version link required by datepicker and stopped giving the error

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this:

```
<div runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#<%=StartDate.ClientID%>').datepicker({ showOn: 'button',
                    buttonImage: '../images/Calendar.png',
                    buttonImageOnly: true, onSelect: function () { },
                    onClose: function () { $(this).focus(); }
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: i tried with both ClientID and also UniqueId
getting this error: i have updated my code above

Comment: are you trying to insert some control dynamically? if your trying to do that then I think you should use a placeholder control and create/insert your control in there.

Comment: i just have a plain web form with all reference in it and just trying to have a datepicker on asp.net control, very simple.

Comment: if your script tag is in the body try nesting it inside a div tag with a runat attribute. I was doing some searching and it seems this can solve the problem, don't know why though.

Comment: here is the error message i am getting:
"Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method"

Answer (score 0):

conflict .js reference (when more than one reference to jquery library within the same page). If you choose to keep more than one reference (but not the best choice, one reference would be better) the $.noConflict(); method could help in this case (see: [enter link description here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) )

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".dtp").datepicker();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This is caused when, on your page, you have a referenced the jquery library more than once.

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
        $(function() {
            $('#datebox').datepicker();
        });
    </script>       
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <input type="text" id="datebox" />
</body>
</html>
```