# MVC3 razor view error Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'datepicker'`

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, datepicker

I am trying to display  a datepicker  for my  Html.EditorFor

To do this I created an EditorTemplate in my Views\Shared\EditorTemplate folder , Named it DateTime.cshtml

but it is not working ,instead I am getting error ---`Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'datepicker'`

Plz help me to fix this error

This is my razor  view page

```
@model MyWebRole.ViewModels.ViewModelEvents
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset style="width:50%">
        <legend>Event Details:</legend>
        <div>
            <table>

                <tr>
                 <td>

                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.vmStartDate)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.vmStartDate)
                    </td>


                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

and here is my DateTime.cshtml (pasted below)

```
@model System.DateTime?

<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",(Model == DateTime.MinValue)? null : Model), new { @class="text"})
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#@ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
            gotoCurrent: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am able to get datepicker working on another view

```
  @model MyWebRole.Models.Events
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <fieldset style="width:50%">
            <legend>Event Details:</legend>
            <div>
                <table>

                    <tr>
                     <td>

                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate)
                        </td>


                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    }
```

The difference between the two razor views is that 
-->the first one( (datepicker not working) is using a ViewModel as model  ie(mywebrole.ViewModels.EventViewModel)

--> and the second one is using the myWebrole.models.Events (datepicker working fine)

Is this an issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Given that error, I think the problem is the selector.  Instead of *$("#@ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName")*, try this one:

```
$("input.text").datepicker({   ...
```

(Alternatively, you could *@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model)* instead of *@Html.TextBox*, so that way the *input* would get *id=PropertyName*, and thus the selector should work).

Also, you're sure the script for the *datepicker* JQuery plugin loaded successfully on the page, right?

Comment: Yes ,The script for the datepicker JQuery plugin loaded successfully on the page .

Comment: I noticed that the datepicker is working fine if I am using mywebrole.models.mymodel ,but is throwing error when I use mywebrole.ViewModels.myViewModel

Comment: @Millar Cool ...  since you posted that other view, I'm positive the selector is the issue.  Just change "#@ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName" to "input.text" and I'll bet it works.

Comment: I changed "#@ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName" to "input.text" ,but I am getting the same error ." Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'datepicker'"

Comment: @Millar smh :(.  I really don't know then.  Here's another SO thread with basically the same issue, turned out to be a script conflict.  Maybe this is the issue:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714494/jquery-datepicker-in-asp-net